# Android NDK debug APK does not package .so files from obj\local\APP_ABI folder

Tags: debugging, android-ndk, java-native-interface, apk, symbols

I am using Eclipse to build Android App that contains 3 sub projects:

Structure of the application is below:

```
 MyApp (Android Application, dependency is set to JNIWrapper)
  |___ JNIWrapper (JNI wrapper for SharedLib, dependency set to SharedLib)
          |____ SharedLib (contains native c/c++ API's, originally developed for Windows)
```

Application builds OK with with release (striped) version of the shared lib from libs/$APP_ABI folder.
How do I force Eclipse to include objects from obj/local/$APP_ABI folder instead in the APK file?
I've set the project dependencies and final the APK seems to have everything I need for a release build.
My main issue is, I am unable to set break points in JNIWrapper and in SharedLib code.

Thanks in advance for the help.
- NK

EDIT --

I've built release objects with debug symbols (with APP_OPTIM := debug and APP_CFLAGS += -g -ggdb -O0 -DDEBUG) . Now I can set break points in JNI and .so files.
But binaries in obj/local/x86 are substantially bigger (800KB Vs 1.5MB) than binaries in libs/x86; I am not sure what extra debugging info I am missing in libs/x86 folder.

EDIT2 --
I've added APP_CPPFLAGS += -ggdb3 -O0 -gdwarf-2 -Wall -DDEBUG; now I can step through and see variable values during debugging in native code.

Issue closed...

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the NDK tools have some level of debug support built-in, without shipping your symbolized shared libs. Have a look at docs for `ndk-gdb`.